# RcppArmadillo and C++ division issue

Tags: rcpp, armadillo

A very simple question regarding RcppArmadillo. Trying to multiply a vector by a scalar, and getting different results depending on small changes in syntax.

Any ideas?

```
// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec funtemp(arma::vec x)              
{
  // return(x/10); // this works
  // return((1/10)*x); // this does not work 
  return(x*(1/10)); // this does not work
}
```

Comment: @Coatless was very generous with his time here.  You basically fell for an (annoying but unavoidable) beginner issue every C / C++ programmer encounters at some point.  This has **nothing** to do with either Rcpp or Armadillo per se.

Answer (score 3):

Ahh, the good ol' `integer` vs. `double` division problem in C++. Before we begin, note that: `arma::vec` is by default a `double`  and `1`, `10`, `1/10` are all `int`s...

Let's take a look at your functions separately:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec funtemp_one(arma::vec x)
{
  return(x/10); // this works
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec funtemp_two(arma::vec x)
{
  return((1/10)*x);  // this does not work
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec funtemp_three(arma::vec x)
{
  return(x*(1/10)); // this does not work
}
```

Therefore, when we run through your problem we get:

```
> funtemp_one(1)
     [,1]
[1,]  0.1

> funtemp_two(1)
     [,1]
[1,]    0

> funtemp_three(1)
     [,1]
[1,]    0
```

In the later functions (e.g. the `1/10`), the `operator/` that is being used is `int` based division. As a result, 2 `int`s enter and 1 `int` is returned. If the result is not divisible, then you end up with a zero being returned as it is outside of the integer scope.

In order to use the double version, which returns a double, at least one of the `int`s must be explicitly cast to a `double`. This happens by default in the first case as you have a `double`/`int` due to `arma::vec`'s structure. The second and third cases have an `int/int` structure that can be dealt with in two ways: 1. use a `.0` after the `int` or 2. explicitly cast the value as a double with `double(int)`

e.g.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec funtemp_four(arma::vec x)
{
  return(x*(1/10.0)); // this works
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec funtemp_five(arma::vec x)
{
  return(x*(1/double(10))); // this works
}
```

Will give what you expect:

```
> funtemp_four(1)
     [,1]
[1,]  0.1

> funtemp_five(1)
     [,1]
[1,]  0.1
```